# Sorting ADO recordset text field as numeric

Tags: vba, ado, adodb

Using VBA i have a set of functions that return an `ADODB.Recordset` where all the columns as `adVarChar`. Unfortunately this means numerics get sorted as text. So 1,7,16,22 becomes 1,16,22,7

Is there any methods that can sort numerics as text columns without resorting to changing the type of the column?

```
Sub TestSortVarChar()

  Dim strBefore, strAfter As String

  Dim r As ADODB.RecordSet

  Set r = New ADODB.RecordSet
  r.Fields.Append "ID", adVarChar, 100
  r.Fields.Append "Field1", adVarChar, 100
  r.Open


  r.AddNew
  r.Fields("ID") = "1"
  r.Fields("Field1") = "A"

  r.AddNew
  r.Fields("ID") = "7"
  r.Fields("Field1") = "B"

  r.AddNew
  r.Fields("ID") = "16"
  r.Fields("Field1") = "C"

  r.AddNew
  r.Fields("ID") = "22"
  r.Fields("Field1") = "D"


  r.MoveFirst
  Do Until r.EOF
    strBefore = strBefore & r.Fields("ID") & " " & r.Fields("Field1") & vbCrLf
    r.MoveNext
  Loop

  r.Sort = "[ID] ASC"


  r.MoveFirst
  Do Until r.EOF
    strAfter = strAfter & r.Fields("ID") & " " & r.Fields("Field1") & vbCrLf
    r.MoveNext
  Loop

  MsgBox strBefore & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strAfter

End Sub
```

NB: I am using Project 2003 and Excel 2003 and referencing **Microsoft ActiveX DataObject 2.8 Library**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left pad with Zeros with at least as many as maximum number digits.
e.g.

0001
0010
0022
1000

You can use Right$() to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Val() function to sort numerically on a text column.  Example:

```
SELECT ID, Field1
FROM tablename
ORDER BY Val(Field1);
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Unfortunately the data isnt generated by a RDBMS, it's just a set of functions that return data in a RecordSet.  These functions can't be changed, so i need to sort the dead RecordSet.